# JQuery click event for element from parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery-1.8.3, and trying to ovveride onclick event for an image html element.

```html
<input id=ClientId1_imgImageID title="Click for larger view" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" type=image name=ClientId1$imgImageID ImageID="3baf5b7b-2246-4be2-a21f-f5b7956e0010"></input>
```

The problem is that this element is generated dynamicly. I could successfuly remove onclick attribute using JQuery code :

```js
function UpdateOnclick(ClientID){
    window.opener.$("#" + ClientID + "_imgImageID").removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

But when I try to add click event, I am failed. I`ve tried different methods, but none of them are working :

**Method 1:**

```js
window.opener.$("#" + ClientID + "_imgImageID").click(function() {  alert('test'); return false; });
```

**Method 2:**

```js
$(window.opener.document).on("click", "#" + ClientID + "_imgImageID" ,function() { alert('test'); return false; });
```

Can anybody help me to understand why onclick event is not applied to  , please ?

Comment: you are also missing a few (" ") in the input.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically added elements you should use Method 2, but u have a mistake there.

Function should look like this:

```
$(window.opener.document).on("click", "#" + ClientID + "_imgImageID" ,function() { alert('test'); return false; });
```

Comment: thank you for correction, but this is still not working for me.